# Hey, i want to sum the lines linked to the same "country'' in one line

Tags: r

My data frame:

```
data.frame(
  Country=c("Germany","France","Spain","Germany","Spain"),
  "01/jan"=c(82,32,44,54,10),
  "01/feb"=c(11,0,1,9,12))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please include code you've tried so far. (Also, this looks like you typed this "data" in manually. Can you provide "real" and unambiguous data by either including how you build the data (e.g., `dat <- data.frame(...)`) or paste the output from `dput(head(x))`.

Comment: i don't have any idea  huw to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Country X01.jan X01.feb
#   <fct>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 France       32       0
# 2 Germany     136      20
# 3 Spain        54      13
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, we can do

```
aggregate(.~ Country, dat, sum)
```